# javascript - JQuery Extend: Error during "OPEN" function: cannot call methods on dialog prior to initialization attempted to call method 'close'

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to extend alert function and let it close after a timeout.
I'm getting this error when close timeout expire:

**cannot call methods on dialog prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'close'**

The code of extension is:

```
$.extend({ alert: function (message, title) {
  $("<div></div>").dialog( {
    buttons: { "Ok": function () { $(this).dialog("close"); } },
    close: function (event, ui) { $(this).remove(); },
    resizable: false,
    title: title,
    modal: true,
    open: function(event, ui) {
        setTimeout(function(){
            $(this).dialog('close');   <-- Error is here
        }, 3000);
    }
  }).text(message);
}
});
```

And the call method is:

```
$.alert('Alert Message Test');
```

Next, after 3000 ms, the dialog should close.
What's wrong?

**UPDATE**

Thanks to Kevin, now it works! Yes, it's the same problem of your reported answer but... it's so hard to find. This question is connected to the JS error.

```
$.extend({ alert: function (message, title) {
  $("<div></div>").dialog( {
    buttons: { "Ok": function () { $(this).dialog("close"); } },
    close: function (event, ui) { $(this).remove(); },
    resizable: false,
    title: title,
    modal: true,
    open: function(event, ui) {
        var that = this;            <-- This is the solution
        setTimeout(function(){
            $(that).dialog('close');
        }, 3000);
    }
  }).text(message);
}
});
```

Comment: `this` isn't what you think it is.

Comment: try logging `this` inside your setTimeout function, it's probably not what you think it is. either reselect your dialog or use an arrow function for your setTimeout callback.

Comment: @KevinB that duplicate should be updated to show using arrow syntax, as likely it's the way forward for these problems. Thoughts?

Comment: eh, not quite yet. IE11 is still mainstream, doing so may cause more problems than it fixes due to people blindly using arrow functions not knowing browser support.

Comment: You 've opened my eyes!!!!

Comment: @azium and, it's already in another answer in the dupe target. :p